# WebStorm is not highlighting JS code

Tags: javascript, syntax, webstorm

WebStorm is not highlighting properly JS code whether its in HTML file or in JS file. It says **unresolved variable or type document** when I want to get ID of element using `document.getElementByiD`.

[image]

I have also captured settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: General thought: please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. Anything interesting in `idea.log` file?

Comment: Check `File -> Settings > Editor -> File Types`, select `JavaScript` into list of file types and check if you have `*.js` into list of extensions below. Alternatively try to create new draft (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Ins) for JavaScript language and take a look if it get highlighted.

Comment: Thank you LazyOne. after invalidating caches it worked again

Comment: @Flying  genius. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**3 Things to try:**

1. Try `File | Invalidate Caches` and restart IDE. (credits @LazyOne)
2. `File -> Settings > Editor -> File Types`, select `JavaScript` into list of file types and check if you have `*.js` into list of extensions below. Alternatively try to create new draft (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Ins) for JavaScript language and take a look if it get highlighted. (credits @Flying)
3. Go to `File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript` and Choose `ECMAScript 5.1` and press ok. Files shoud now be highlighted correctly. Then, open the menu again and re-select `ECMAScript 6+`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same or similar problem. Unresolved variables did not "highlight". But the problem occurred only on a single .mjs -file as far as I could tell. In others it did highlight those errors.

This was a big problem because I had  a large set of JavaScript code which took much time to test-run to see how it worked, and having mistyped variable names caused it to fail but only after running it again and again after making any change.

I tried many things which did not help but finally this action got the unresolved variables error-highlighting to work again:

1. Open the file with missing error-highlights in WebStorm editor.
2. From the top menu-bar navigate
   Code ->  Analyze Code -> Configure Current File Analysis
3. Choose "All Problems" (instead of "Syntax")

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I added an .eslintrc file but our project is using TS Lint. I just disabled eslint and things started working again.